# Extract Content after Match

Tags: powershell

I would like to partially automate the configuration of our Aruba switch using the daily configuration *.cfg backups.

With the following command I get the desired block of a vlan from the Configfile:

```
$content=Get-Content -Path $switch.fullname | Select-String 'vlan 53' -Context 0,4
```

The result can then look like this, for example:

```
> vlan 53
 name "WIFI"
 tagged 5,8,47-52
 no ip address
 exit
```

Does anyone know how I can extract only the "tagged" vlan ports from $Content?
I would then like to use these in further steps for configuration.

Maybe via magic regex commands.

But unfortunately I am too stupid for that.

Many thanks in advance

Daniel

Comment: `... |Out-String |Select-String '(?<=tagged\s*)\S+'`

Comment: Thank you for your input.
I will see if I can get this analysed. Result: ($content | Out-String |Select-String '(?<=tagged\s*)\S+').Matches.Value

Comment: Can you explain to me why regex101.com criticises the * but regexr.com has no problem with it?
Powershell delivers a correct result with and without *.
https://regex101.com/r/VX8eIT/1
https://regexr.com/741q1

Comment: [Select-String is based on lines of text.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string#description) therefore it will only include `\s*` (any white spaces) right after the word `tagged` (up to the end of the line) in the [look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). [`regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/), however, will take the multiline string as a whole and therefore possibly also include newline characters (as carriage returns and line feeds) in the look behind. You might also consider a literal space: `'(?<=tagged *)\S+'`